# How can I trigger an element with multiple different data layers depending on the click area?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to have a tag fire when someone clicks an the Google Rating box on the top right of [this website](https://www.virginiagreenlawncare.com/v2/) (it's a Google Rating box that opens up a lightbox). The problem is, depending on where you click the element, it fires different information in the data layer.

I would fix this just by using regex to trigger when clicking a variable type with "variable1|variable2|variable3..." etc. but again, depending on where you click the element it doesn't even fire the same variable type. I've been working on this a few hours an exhausted every "element visibility", "css selector", and "custom event" tag I can think of.

**How can I set up a trigger that fires the tag whenever the Google Rating box is clicked?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to match click element class since all elements within the widget have a class that start with "wp-google" or "wp-star". Example:

[image]